# What does loop do with graph vertexes in Union Find algorithm?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to learn `Union Find` algorithm.
There is a function that accepts vertex number of graph:

```
 // Find which component/set 'p' belongs to, takes amortized constant time.
    find(p) {
        // Find the root of the component/set
        let root = p;
        while (root != this.id[root])
            root = this.id[root];
        // Compress the path leading back to the root.
        // Doing this operation is called "path compression"
        // and is what gives us amortized time complexity.
        while (p != root) {
            let next = this.id[p];
            this.id[p] = root;
            p = next;
        }
        return root;

    }
```

Full code is provided by [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&strictNullChecks=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECqB2BLA9vAYo%20ATaBvAUPtNAPQlwQCmOALstDQE5jADWDAFpdBIgF7dkAM2iUWHaMM7dgyALYAHVJXg0i0BY0QA3MDW4Q%20ALmjwArnIBGlRgG0AutAC80BwG5CxMtERZbiRyVMGhg6aQ0wRhUaSRFEABofOL8A5x9peHTEGDBoRmRkGPhkLEp1TR09bl8Tcysbd09ScgAVZjZQrlMLa0ZY6FlFZVUYTHCzJFRoIUwscq1dfW65AGF5JXhoiFqemw9ys0sQRGAB1AgmM2A6RgAKBUPj04B9XgEd%20sYASjwm4kQRLdXvxuAAeFwABh%20NA4%20QA7tBbgAiADKIOg4OgEJ8MGKMTAIBAyDh1CRX32xGIMOyADo6mshpsRmlqRAacCBB5KZxaYY0psEQBBRjMACet1Z7LelHJ6ipHFpvn5lCFIrA4slHJlFMpQmQfVuIEoMUQaQhbnSoOgWotiAA1HafgRufLFSlHC5EBbvAAZTDsMKIEKUECAqihvIFGhfOWUyWGfwe6AARm95AAouIzozojjJFoAOaYAkgUX9aWSTaxgC%20TVr6m8GGw0DhCuAEkGG2iJCoMQA5Ao%209BrET4AXQshEjQwKxKDk5PqaCCcLJ4BcwKoGIg5JQaQcjidprN7h9ek6-s1oE3aF18oV%20jCZOthjQe8bY0aYneYi4FFzKa2iBGoi37QAAhC4kq%20LY372D8oGQQqbLQbBOpeOQDKaHOnTcAoegSEaYBYJgBbDiwAb0I%20kaFHu3LeAAIsgJE8jAyAKDYegoJk2QDCW1DQEieEwtmWFQFxSKxt4G44DxrZ6NARbaHO0BmPOi7LluO4iUaAAeQairRAEKsB9zgS437ni60CfqYlA6T%20LE0tBCj2P%203JQX4LlpN%20bmUgoyr2b59bclENBmIwmQ%20eowWXi0SF5hu0AEvoEWcUpeSUMA4W8OleqMHIZjgEuUx5eEMzNjuMIlA25APAepzBEe2C3I1CiWZe-yAv5Tiep5cEZWFEUaP%203jEKF4XcX1aTlVgLV9bK6HQDF3gAErGhNLZcI%20fT6qY95USGlA7syA5DtJNXQH2ACOZ1RD4mRURAYBaZ2L4QG%20NCGXVTxnPAmzXNQJ51L0iRXUYwM2O1Y3rUNkozfcPw9Y58NXQtS1NKtMMPV0FZSFRr1MiEH2XYOw4hqg44MMg%204-SJL5ogIJ7LGevwhVjjkJnDx5ta50UY%20Qa2Ddj3AQztIiHcdIT3SxcCTOgswkPR2QAFZMZuvY04e0q3FDA0bZq0r-stAtYzhzM2P0URyGAmDMQTWwfRAmunPbIw66zlLjbDSF0hYmFvUb-OywCZb48%20hPvb2MCrtOttjqIRqSzAp1Jc2119s7xATCHQO7IwoPg3n56xsQpSWGYBYFnsF7eHFc7cBLWxJXdBJRERZZjI9z3cAW%20RmAoYGxgCiKSqu-36LNCig188FY2h1nGtRNDJiyPvw21vk2UvABMq%200ijsqSeQACyNhVzw1uEhbruvr291hFR4CMFXO2bIZnUjz7CbfsmjhWvGfAYJRm3v1Z0LoAFAMKCA6AdpEK8kAT-XmVkPKQOXkmb829fKujZN-KMv8zRBQTlQD27kv4ILwY4WBHNyFQKQeAn2KFgHoLwVg6hqDoGQiCjXcgaJ4DAG4FRb8MA9QTBwJEbgxEhBCBsLmEk0BWDFARDCeSj4j7mzFnTCOjtoAcEgNAUowA25UBwJYMsyhYySnpOHLYABaGxgd6xMDLAQGyuQXACmDqga8twADMsowA0mzkIcUyZEjb38YEpAwTbjb0SH4jw1ZeI0HbIiGUeBVwQGQEaGkRICy3BlNWIAA)

I can't get what is happening here:

```
let root = p;
while (root != this.id[root])
       root = this.id[root];
```

Income vertex `p` is assinged to `root`. Then something happens in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.id` is a mapping between indices from current to parent. The loop tries to follow the mapping starting at `p`, one mapping step at a time and stops if it finds a mapping that maps to itself.

For `[0,2,0]` starting at `p=1` we see a 2, go to index 2, see a 0, go to index 0, see a 0 again, are done.

Comment: `this.id` is it vertexes numbers? Is it ways(connections) from vertexes?

Comment: @Jony sort of, yes. `// id[i] points to the parent of i, if id[i] = i then i is a root node`

Comment: It is still hard to understand, usually connections between points we see in dictionary like: `A = {B,C}
B = {D,E}`

Comment: *Usually* simply does not matter, the `id` is a mapping from the index to its parent, as the comment in the code says. No point in arguing that you do not expect that or would implement it differently, the code is documented that way and works that way.